# Trigger - when I reply to a answer

Tags: feature-request

When I answer a question on Stack Overflow, I'd like to have these two additional checkboxes:

- [] Notify ___________________ on other new answers
- [] Notify ___________________ on new votes

Also, if I post a comment, does the post owner get an email alert? Sometime I'm crossing my fingers to get a clarification quickly, but the poster never came back to Stack Overflow and thus never saw or responded to my comment.

NB: Anyone can hack my information? I am pretty sure I didn't wrote this!! My English is very bad.

Comment: I'm not sure that my edit reflects what you meant, so feel free to rollback and/or clarify if I misunderstood.

Comment: @balpha, I was halfway through doing that same thing.  But I wasn't sure enough of what I thought he meant.

Comment: @Justin sorry for tripping over you then :)

Comment: Votes on *your* answer appear in your recent activity and are flagged by the envelope changing colour.

Comment: @ChrisF: No, they're not -- votes don't trigger the envelope.

Comment: @balpha - well you learn something new every day. I've been using the sites for well over a year and always assumed that they did. But then again the first thing I do when returning to a site is to check the recent activity page to see which (if any) of my answers have attracted votes.

Comment: @ChrisF: It's probably because you know your repution was X when you went to bed, and the first thing you notice in the morning is that it's not X anymore, but X+30 -- even before you see the envelope lighting up :)

Comment: Re your edit: Yes, anybody can hack your information. Or, to be precise, people with enough reputation can edit any post. That's why I said above "I'm not sure that my edit reflects what you meant, so feel free to rollback and/or clarify if I misunderstood." after I edited your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want notifications of activity on a specific question you can click the cool Star right below the vote buttons.

[image: star and unstar a question]

Once you click the Star, the question becomes a Favorite.  You will then receive notifications of activity on that question.

Comment: Comments, new answers and edits to answers (I think) - but not votes.

Comment: @Chris, correct, you cannot see votes.

Comment: You'll receive a ping when answers are edited, but it won't show up in your Recent Activity. Also, only comments to the question body will ping.

Comment: Thanks, The STAR icon works. But VOTES i never received alert in my mail box. Lets say 10 years later or half year later, if someone vote me once, and i dont have email alert, i will even wont't know what happend.

Comment: @Justin..: Never mind, i just put another question and put start on, many experts replied, voted i never yet got a single email alert. Maybe its better to have a quick process for this. As always feature requests are optional...

Comment: @StackFan.  You will just have to track changes in reputation.  If you see that your rep has changed you can click on the envelope on the top of the screen and view which post caused the rep change.